# Replace value after Nth delimiter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Original string looks like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e
```

How can I replace the comma separated value that comes after the Nth comma?

So for example how can i replace the value that comes after 3rd comma with `x` to create a following string?

`a,b,c,x,e`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mystr = 'a,b,c,d,e'

mystr = mystr.split(',')
mystr[3] = 'x'
mystr = ','.join(mystr)

print mystr
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you want to do it, there are several ways, e.g.:

using split

```
list = "a,b,c,d,e".split(",")
list[3] = "x"
print ",".join(list)
```

using regex

```
import re
print re.sub(r"^((?:[^,]+,){3})([^,]+)(.*)$", "\\1x\\3", "a,b,c,d,e")
```

in the regexp example, `{3}` is how many entries to skip

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible

`def replaceNthComma(data, indexOfComma, newVal):
    _list = list(data)
    _list[indexOfComma*2] = newVal
    return ''.join(_list)`

Which will return the exact ouput as you expect.

`ouput: replaceNthComma("a,b,c,x,e", 3, 'x') ==> 'a,b,c,x,e'`

Answer (score 0):

The code I am posting here should be self-explanatory, if not, feel free to ask for explanations with a comment.

```
s = 'a,b,c,d,e'
n = 3
to_replace_with = 'x'

l = s.split(',')
l[n] = to_replace_with
result = ','.join(l)

>>>print(result)
'a,b,c,x,e'
```